# Which language is this (Wordpress)?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm debugging the WordPress-Code and in the file media-template.php I found code that looks like this:

```
<# if ( ! _.isEmpty( data.model.src ) ) {
if ( isYouTube ) { #>
<source src="{{ data.model.src }}" type="video/youtube" />
```

Can someone give me a hint what language this is? This is not PHP. How will the variable data.model.src be filled?

This full source code can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/media-template.php

Comment: Comment on line #51: "Output the markup for a video tag to be used in an **Underscore template**" (highlight by me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats Backbone JS
You can lookup whats actually happening with this [here](https://medium.com/@coreyhowell/javascript-for-the-impatient-backbonejs-part-1-7f4dba8fcea).